# how to create a @keyframes mixin in SCSS (3.1.16)

Tags: sass, mixins, keyframe

I already tried

```
$prefixes: ("-webkit-","-moz-", "-o-", "");
@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
        @#{$prefix}keyframes #{$name} { @content; }
    }
}
```

and

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} { @content; }
    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} { @content; }
    @keyframes #{$name} { @content; }
}
```

any way to do this? Couldn't find any solutions with Google :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve this effect by updating to SASS 3.2 (pre-release via `gem install sass --pre`), as a result latter now works!

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't forget to add @-ms-keyframes as well

Comment: This wouldn't work for me – for a start, SASS attempts to parse the `@` at the beginning of `@#{$prefix}`, so I needed to escape that with a `\ `. But then I get `Invalid CSS after "$prefix": expected ":", was "@content"` – which makes no sense at all AFAICT. What versions were you using for this?

Comment: as already stated in my answer: `SASS 3.2` - although this should be supported in every current stable versions of SASS by now.